# Makefile: Need help to build source files from different directories to a specific object directory

Tags: c, linux, makefile, gnu-make

I'm writing a Makefile for my project. The project is something like this:

```
 config.mk - variables like CC, CFLAGS, PREFIX, etc.
 obj
 src
  |--- include
  |--- foo1
  |     |--- 1.c
  |     |--- 2.c
  |     L--- unwanted1.c
  L--- foo2
        |--- bar1
        |     |---3.c
        |     |---4.c
        |     |---unwanted2.c
        |     L---unwanted3.c
        |--- bar2
              |---5.c
              L---6.c
```

I wanted to exclude the unwanted .c files (they were used in a different part of the build process), build them then put the created object files in obj. But I don't know how to build them yet.
This is what I've been able to write (and worked):

```
# Compiler setting are defined here:
include config.mk     

SRCS = src/foo1/1.c src/foo1/2.c \
       src/foo2/bar1/3.c src/foo2/bar1/4.c \
       src/foo2/bar2/5.c src/foo2/bar2/5.c
OBJS = $(addprefix obj/,$(notdir $(SRCS:.c=.o)))
```

But I don't know how to write the building part. Answers I've found used %.c and %.o, which is impossible in this case.
I tried writing it like this:

```
$(OBJS): $(SRCS)
        ${CC} -fPIC -c -Isrc/include ${CFLAGS} -o $@ $<
lib: $(OBJS)
        ${CC} -shared -o lib.so -Wl,-soname="lib.so" $(OBJS)
```

But it didn't work.
`make: *** No rule to make target 'obj/bar1.o', needed by 'lib'.  Stop.`

How can I rewrite the building part to make it work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see any way you could get that error from the makefile you provided so there must be some mismatch between what you actually did and what you posted here.

Answer (score 0):

Your current attempt can't work because it expands to:

```
obj/1.o obj/2.o ... : src/foo1/1.c src/foo1/2.c ...
```

and make parses this exactly as if you'd written:

```
obj/1.o : src/foo1/1.c src/foo1/2.c ...
obj/2.o : src/foo1/1.c src/foo1/2.c ...
  ...
```

which not only will do the wrong thing (because `$<` is always the same file: `src/foo1/1.c` so you'll always compile the same file) but will rebuild *all* the object files whenever *any* object file changes.

First let me say, it's a bad idea to dump all your object files into a single directory.  What if you have `src/foo1/1.c` and then you also create `src/foo2/bar1/1.c`?  You're basically saying, yes I have a complex data structure for all my sources, but even so they all must have unique names.  A better idea is to mirror the source structure in the object directory, then you just need this:

```
OBJS = $(patsubst %.c,obj/%.o,$(SRCS))

obj/%.o: %.c
        @mkdir -p $(@D)
        ${CC} -fPIC -c -Isrc/include ${CFLAGS} -o $@ $<
```

If you really, really want to put all .o's into a single directory the best way to do it is with VPATH:

```
VPATH = $(sort $(dir $(SRCS)))
OBJS = $(addprefix obj/,$(notdir $(SRCS:.c=.o)))

obj/%.o: %.c
        ${CC} -fPIC -c -Isrc/include ${CFLAGS} -o $@ $<
```